# JavaScript WebAudio API Analyser low-pass-filter in Firefox 51

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm using an AnalyserNode to verify high frequencies captured from microphone, the code I implement is working properly on Edge and Chrome, but for some reason, it doesn't work on Firefox.

It's like Firefox has a default low-pass-filter, low frequencies are captured normally, although high frequencies (above 12000Hz) are attenuated. So when I generate a signal above 12000Hz Firefox captured nothing, no oscillation in my graph is notice.

I already tried to use BiquadFilterNode to set highpass, it attenuated low frequencies, but did nothing to higher frequencies.

A little piece of my code:

```
var input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var biquadFilter = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
biquadFilter.type = "highpass";
biquadFilter.frequency.value = 10000;
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
biquadFilter.connect(analyser);
input.connect(biquadFilter);
```

Is there a "default" config in Firefox that makes it ignore high frequencies on microphone or some way workaround this?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same problem. I am working on audio digital modulator in frequencies above 16KHz. Works fine in Chrome. Can I ask what you are working on?

Comment: BTW: also tried setting min and max decibels which is great on chrome to accentuate the  higher frequencies but still does not work on Firefox.analyser = acontext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
    analyser.minDecibels = -150;
    analyser.maxDecibels = 20;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;

Comment: @KerryDavis I was working on a college project, but I never found out what was happening. Sorry.. My guess is that is a bug on Firefox.